# Sonar integration with jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sonar-runner, sonarqube-5.0

I am trying to integrate sonar builds from jenkins. I am getting the below error:

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar
>   (default-cli) on project ibis: Fail to connect to database: Cannot
>   load JDBC driver class 'org.h2.Driver' -> [Help 1]

It is clear that I need to upload j**dbc mysql driver** somewhere in the configuration.
I do not know where and how to do it.

Comment: You talk about _mysql_ driver but Jenkins is complaining about _h2_ driver. Are you able to provide your sonar settings from Jenkins and from your actual Sonar server?

Comment: I have my sonar and jenkin server up. Later in my jenkin configurations i have installed sonar pluggin and provided my sonar server details. But when i execute the jenkin job it fails and gives me above error. I have configured my sonar server to use mysql instead of h2 db which is default. In the error it is complaining about h2 driver miss when if at all I am expecting a mysql driver miss. I am not sure on the configurations. There is a possibility I have missed something in the configuration. It would be helpful if someone can guide me to a setup/config document.

Comment: I found the problem. When you run Sonar in Maven without a configuration, Maven will still use the default database. We need to add a profile in the Maven settings. In the .m2 folder, open the settings.xml. Than add the code below. You also need to do that in the settings.xml in your Maven conf folder. In my case i updated the settings.xml of jenkins .m2 folder

Comment: <profile>
    <id>sonar</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>     
    <properties>
        <sonar.jdbc.url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar</sonar.jdbc.url>
        <sonar.jdbc.username>root</sonar.jdbc.username>
        <sonar.jdbc.password></sonar.jdbc.password>
        <sonar.jdbc.driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</sonar.jdbc.driver>
    </properties>
</profile>

Comment: I imagine you are running mvn sonar:sonar goal and that way you need to specify the configuration somewhere in your settings.xml. However, given that you have the Sonar plugin installed for Jenkins, you could take advantage of it by running the code quality stage using the plugin itself. You can do so by running a the Post-build step called _SonarQube_. Doing so, the job will grab the configuration of Sonar from Jenkins. In any case, happy to hear that you found the problem.